# Items inside the combobox not showing

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add some items to a combo box in VB, but when I add the items to the click event handler of the combo-box, and run the code, the items added do not show.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.Refresh()
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Mondad")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Tuesday")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Wenesday")
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1
End Sub
```

I mean nothing shows inside the combo-box.

Comment: *"I add the items to the click event"* - The method name implies otherwise.  When you debug, is this method ever invoked?  What happens when you debug?

Comment: When someone picks an item in the combo box, you are wiping the combo box, and then refilling it, and selecting an item for them. Why would you do that?

Comment: That's not a click event.  If this code actually worked, it would lock up the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your code i think it will work

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Click
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Mondad")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Tuesday")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Wenesday")
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1
    End Sub
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

> I add the items to the click event handler of the combo-box

Pay special attention to the name of the method:

```
ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()
```

Note the emphasis. It sure looks like this is *NOT* the click event. The click event method would look like this:

```
ComboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Just changing the name of the method will not be enough, because the method still will not be wired up correctly. Create a new empty event handler in Visual Studio for the click event and move the code there.

Comment: In VB you can just change the part after the `Handles`

Comment: The code most likely belongs in the form's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Put in form load

```
  `  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Mondad")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Tuesday")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Wenesday")

End Sub`
```